# How to create a new table with the select query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert the obtained query (**below exposed, see:code**) into a new table so I can compute and process the data more easily..

I know this question sounds stupid, but when I use:

```
  SELECT X.*

  INTO NewTable

 FROM

 (

         SELECT .... complex query ....

         FROM ...

          ...

  ) AS X
```

**It sends me an error message, how am I supposed to enter my query into this code above mentioned..**

**Error:**

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 54

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Code:

```
  SELECT *

  INTO Price_to_book_valid

  FROM

  (

    select *

    from pricetobook

    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    declare @fields nvarchar(max);

    set @fields=stuff((select ',['+column0+']'
           from dll_ptbv
           where column0 not in ('Code','Mnemonic')
           group by column0
           order by case when column0='Name' then 0 else 3 end
           ,column0
           for xml path('')
          ,type
           ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
           ,1 ,1 ,'');
  set@sql='select'+@fields 
     + 'from (select column0
                    ,column1
                    ,sum(rn1*rn2) over(order by rn2) as rn
             from (select column0
                         ,column1
                         ,case when column0=''Name'' then 1 else 0 end as rn1
                         ,row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn2
                 from dll_ptbv
                 ) as a
            ) as a
 pivot (max(column1) for column0 in ('+@fields+')) as p
 order by [Name]';
  execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: "It sends me an error message", why not share the error message?

Comment: Done! I really though it was it, sorry

Comment: You are mixing static sql with dynamic sql. It can't work like this. You have to execute the results of your dynamic sql into a table (regular, temporary or variable) and use that table with your static sql.

Comment: and how do I insert my results into a regular, temporary or variable table ? thanks for the help btw

Comment: read about `insert... exec`

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE GetDBNames
AS
SELECT name, database_id
FROM sys.databases
GO

Comment: and then: SELECT * INTO #TestTableT FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC tempdb.dbo.GetDBNames')
-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #TestTableT;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- 14. SELECT INTO new table from dynamic stored procedure execution.

---

### -- Dynamic stored procedure to temporary table

```
         USE tempdb; 
           GO 
             -- SQL create dynamic stored procedure

             CREATE PROCEDURE DynamicSprocToTempTable 
                AS 
                  BEGIN 
             DECLARE  @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT top (5) * from AdventureWorks.Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader 
            ORDER BY NEWID()' 
         -- Dynamic SQL
             EXEC Sp_executesql    @SQL 
               END 
             GO 

          -- Test stored procedure
       EXEC tempdb.dbo.DynamicSprocToTempTable 
            GO 
        -- Select into temporary table from OPENQUERY
        -- SQL select into temp table 
         SELECT * INTO   #poh 
                FROM   Openquery(SERVERALPHA,'exec tempdb.dbo.DynamicSprocToTempTable') 
         GO 

             SELECT PurchaseOrderID, VendorID, OrderDate 
                FROM   #poh
```

/* Results

PurchaseOrderID  VendorID    OrderDate

2662              50          2004-05-19 00:00:00.000

2454              44          2004-05-01 00:00:00.000

2547              96          2004-05-10 00:00:00.000

901               54          2003-10-13 00:00:00.000

2675              74          2004-05-22 00:00:00.000

*/

GO

Answer (score 0):

You coudl use a select INTO before column  Name

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable 
FROM
(
     SELECT .... complex query .... 
     FROM ...
      ...
) p   <<<<<<<< remove as
```

( you should remove as  in as a)   fist you should assign  a table name and eventulally after you can use an alais

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Update your question and show your exact  code you  are using

Comment: Done ( I deleted the " AS X") and know I just get:                                           Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

Comment: do I put it in the end of the query this part **" ) a"** ? bc it keeps sending error with the keyword **declare**

Comment: Could be is p  (not a )  the last form  for your dinamic select generated table

Comment: It's getting hard, even with **p**   ......................                                                                                         Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near ')'.